# How to open this door in The Binding of Isaac: Repentance?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-repentance

[image]

I don't know how to open this door. I have seen it 5 times and can't find a way to open it.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please consider accepting it by clicking the green tick

Answer (score 3):

That's a [Strange Door](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/A_Strange_Door):

According to Isaac wiki, a **Strange Door** is a special exit that is unlocked by beating Mother for the first time. It leads to a special version of Mausoleum/Gehenna II, which contains:

> Dad's Note, which starts the Ascent, and eventually Home and the fight against  Dogma and The Beast.

The door spawns in the starting room of Depths/Necropolis/Dank Depths II. It can be opened by giving it *The Polaroid* or *The Negative*, or by other methods you can find on the linked webpage.

Comment: Also, since you can't normally leave the Mom fight after getting the Polaroid or Negative, there is a guaranteed skull with an X on it somewhere on the Depths 2 that drops a Fool card when destroyed, allowing you to teleport out of the Mom fight to return to that door.